# Fetching facebook data once logged in using django-social-auth

Tags: django, facebook, django-facebook

We've set up an application that uses the `django-social-auth` extension to authenticate users with Facebook. The authentication works fine, but we are not clear on how to go about fetching useful information from Facebook (friends lists, likes, etc.)
It appears that `django-facebook` handles some of this functionality, but also handles the authorization aspects. Is there an application that would sit neatly on top of `django-social-auth` and provide a framework for using facebook data? Using `django-social-auth` and `django-facebook` together seems kludgy.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy).  You could use the Facebook oAuth access token that django-social-auth saves in your database and make whichever Graph API calls your application is permitted to make for the given user.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too hard to roll it yourself. The Facebook graph API is just HTTP get requests with the access_token, and it returns JSON data.