# Get Facebook user likes in Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm starting a project with Django and I'm trying to allow users log in with Facebook. For the site purposes, I want to store the user likes in my database.

I took as an example the example app on Python Social Auth (the library I'm using for the project) and I've written a pipeline for storing data in DB.

The problem comes when I try to access likes, because the data that the response I get just gives me the basic data, so the following code doesn't work.

```
def user_details(strategy, details, response, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    attrs = {'user': user}
    if strategy.backend.__class__.__name__ == 'FacebookOAuth2':
        #no response['likes']
        for i in response['likes']:
            for d in i['data']:
                p = UserPreferences(user=user,like=d['name'])
                p.save()
```

My app in Facebook asks for likes permissions, and I have the following on my settings.py (with the secret and all that stuff):

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_SCOPE = ['user_likes']
```

Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the setting `SOCIAL_AUTH_SCOPE` to `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE`. Likes aren't sent automatically in the auth process, you need to query them to Facebook API, for example:

```
def get_likes(strategy, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if strategy.backend.name == 'facebook':
        likes = strategy.backend.get_json(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/likes' % response['id'],
            params={'access_token': response['access_token']}
        )
        for like in likes['data']:
            pass  # Process and save likes here
```

Comment: Does this approach take into account pagination of Facebook Graph API responses?